# C++ implicit type conversion in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I had a function: `void foo(bool boolParam = true)`

And I changed it to: `void foo(const char* charParam, bool boolParam = true)`

To avoid searching I just compiled the code hoping that the compiler will give an error (or at least an warning) where the function was called because of wrong parameter type, but instead of this the compiler silently converted false to `NULL` and compiled everything without error or warning. Is this behavior correct? I know that false and `NULL` are both 0, but I think the compiler should give at least some warning message...

Comment: Eh, it probably should give you some kind of warning, but I imagine this is because `NULL` is simply #defined in `windows.h` as `0`. Good question, though.

Comment: If you set the warning level to 4 (in the project settings) you should get some warnings.

Comment: @Volker: Are you sure that /W4 will produce a warning about this?

Comment: Same behavior is in GCC 4.2 on Mac OS

Comment: @Cody Gray, I just tested with /W4 and it produces no warnings

Comment: you can define foo(const char * &charParam) .. and compile to get the errors ... and remove & later ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is entirely correct, because (as you note) the conversion from `false` (a valid null pointer constant) to pointer is implicit. Try a `std::string` instead.

Comment: I don't think the conversion from bool to pointer is implicit. When I change from false to true I have the fallowing error: error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'const char *'. Before was correct just because false is 0 as NULL.

Answer (score 7):

You could leave your original function unimplemented:

```
void foo(bool boolParam = true);
void foo(const char* charParam, bool boolParam = true)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Now whenever you call `foo()`, `foo(true)`, and `foo(false)` it will cause a compile error. However, `foo(NULL)` won't compile either because NULL and false are ambiguous (and then we are back to square one...).

Comment: @templatetypedef I did test this with VS. I suppose it's because `foo(true)` and `foo(false)` satisfy the first function better than the second function and, because the first function is unimplemented, it causes a compiler error. That's my educated guess.

Comment: @Marlon- Ah, I missed that the first function was unimplemented.  That's pretty clever!  I should read things more carefully before commenting. XD